# Vector equation of $y=3$

Tags: vectors

I am struggling with converting the Cartesian equation of $y=3$ into a Vector equation in the form $r = a + λb$ . The provided answer is $r = [0,3] + λ[1,0]$.

From my understanding, $y=3$ appears to have a gradient of 'zero' and thus no directional vector. Hence, shouldn't the directional vector be at least $[0,0]$ instead of $[1,0]$ ?

I certainly shall appreciate all guidance.

Comment: $y=3$ is the vertical line consisting of all points whose $y$ value is 3. In the parametrized equation, both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are given as functions of $\lambda$: $r(\lambda) = [x(\lambda), y(\lambda)]$. Here $x(\lambda) = \lambda$ and $y(\lambda) = 3$, so the $y$-coordinate is constant.

Comment: @catherine I think you mean a horizontal line.

Comment: @bobeyt6 Yes, horizontal! (Too late to edit now)

Comment: @catherine Thanks for your input. I have to admit, however, that I am still rather confused. Is it possible if you could please explain it in more simpler terms, specifically about why the direction vector is $[1,0]$ instead of $[0,0]$?

Comment: In the equation $a+\lambda b$, $a$ is a point on the line and $b$ is a vector on the line. For a horizontal line, what is a good candidate for that vector?

Comment: @qwerty The equation traces out all points on the line. If it were $[0,0]$, that would just give a single point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of $y=3$ is indeed $0$, but that does not mean it does not have any direction. If the vector equation were $(0,3)+λ[0,0]$, that would mean it would just be the point $(0,3)$, since $[0,0]$ represents absolutely no change. However, $y=3$ is a horizontal line, which means while the $y$-value is fixed, the $x$-value is changing. Thus, our equation is $(0,3)+λ[1,0]$, so we have some change on the $x$-coordinate. The $y$ component of the vector remains $0$ since the $y$ does not change from $3$.

Comment: Thank you! Just clarifying though, would it be possible in technicality to have $[0.5, 0]$, for example, instead of $[1,0]$?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is a scalar multiple of $[1,0]$(so any $[a,0]$ will do)